# Is multi-touch/gestures supported on all smartphone browsers (Android and iOS)?

Tags: android, ios, browser, multi-touch, gesture

**Background:**

- My website has a page where I need my users/customers to draw a model of their design.
- For this, I am planning to create a very simple SVG-based drawing tool using HTML5-Javascript.
- I would like the tool to work across the standard browsers on iOS and Android phones (3.x and later).

**Question**:

- For the proposed drawing tool on my webpage, I would like to take advantage of Multitouch and Gesture support in particular -- But are they supported in the standard BROWSERS on iOS and Android (3.x and later)?

( Because, if not, the only other option will be to develop two native (and non-browser) apps separately for both platforms, correct? )

Comment: Multitouch isn't a guarantee on all Android phones period, let alone their browsers.  I grant you that modern devices will all have it, but if you're crazy enough to extend your support back to Donut or Cupcake, you'll have to accept single touch only.

Comment: @scriptocalypse: Understood. Also, I have updated the question to include Android version numbers that I am OK with targeting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS Safari Version 3.2, Android Browser 2.1, BlackBerry Browser 7.0 and newer support HTML5 touch events.

Source: http://caniuse.com/#feat=touch.

Comment: BTW, that compatibility website you referred to is great!

Answer (score 1):

I found this [article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch/) that seems to suggest that android beyond Gingerbread and iOS should be reliable in responding to multi-touch events.

Answer (score 1):

You could use corona and develop both apps at once. Corona is easier than developing in xcode. I don't use corona since it can limit you, but doing a web app wouldn't matter at all.
The browsers 2-touch capabilities are mainly used for zooming, selection, and other edits to the page, so you won't be able to receive them, at least not well. You can have them use 1 finger, but two fingers are used for the browser functions.